# How to rebind the click event after using the one method?

Tags: jquery

How to get the click event rebind after using one method?

```
    $("#file").one("click", function(event)
    {   
     // code works only one time as expected.
     $(this).bind("click") // attempting to rebind it again after executing code but not binding again tested below.    
    });
```

before clicking the one method above, the click event is attached to element    #file but after clicking the one method, it shows the click event is unbind using the code below

```
    $(".viewAttachedEvents").click(function()
    {
    var eventFile = $._data(document.getElementById("file"),"events");      
    var File = JSON.stringify(eventFile);
    alert("eventFile: "+File+");
     });
```

Comment: `bind()` expects a function, it doesn't know what you want to bind when you just pass an event name.  What *exactly* are you trying to do here?  Why do you need to use `.one()`?

Comment: You're not specifying which handler to bind to the click event. However, why are you using `one` when you want the handler to stay bound?

Comment: What is `eventFile`?  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I"m using the one method to prevent many clicks and it works. When using on method many clicks happens and causes problems.

Comment: So you want to prevent the event from being triggered multiple times too quickly?  If you'd be willing to use [`underscore.js`](http://underscorejs.org/), it has a function to help with this.  http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it seemed to work, though it seems rather non elegant.

```
$("#file").one("click", function(event)
{   
     setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('#file').click(function(){console.log('bound again')}); 
     },2000); 
});
```

EDIT:

This seems to work too - I am sure there is a cleaner way:

```
$("#file").one("click", function(){   
     //do something
     rebindMe.call($(this));
   });

var rebindMe = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).one('click', function(){
        //do something
        rebindMe($(this));
    }); 
 },4000); // set to 4 seconds. can change it. 
}
```

Comment: thanks James but how do I rebind it to the #file element after using the one method?

Comment: I just edited it, hopefully it works how you want. I assume, you click once.. its "unbound" for a some time, then rebound again..another click, unbound for sometime, then rebound again?
That should work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a little redundant to me, use the `.one` method when you only want one click. Rebinding a click event after the event has finished running its code would be more trivial with just a little abstraction using `.on` and `.off`.

```
var bindTo = $(document),
    clickEvent = function(event) 
    {
        // Unbind event
        bindTo.off('click', '#file', clickEvent);

        // Run your event logic

        // Rebind the event
        bindTo.on('click', '#file', clickEvent);
    };

bindTo.on('click', '#file', clickEvent);
```

Comment: Your code works but does not fix this problem, thanks anyway.